# How to get different inputs in the same line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to get different inputs in the same line in java, but instead of just printing them all at once i want to store then as a string or integer e.t.c...
I can´t find a solution, thanks.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can import them by a deliminator then call the split function on the string and store the results in an array.

```
String input = scan.nextLine();
//Your input is: FirstName, LastName, DOB
String[] inputArr = input.split[","];
// inputArr[0] -> "firstName" etc..
```